# How to run my OpenCV cpp code using Microsoft Azure?

Tags: c++, azure, opencv

I've written an OpenCV code to evaluate NN for its capability of classification for segmenting. It took a long time to get the result for a small portion of code to be executed; due to the high availability of Microsoft Azure, it would be a chance to increase the pace for modeling.

I am interested in how to run this cpp OpenCV code on Azure cloud, including how to transfer cpp code and some training and test images on Azure. My code is long and though it is not included here but I can send the link if needed.

I've googled for how to use Microsoft Azure with cpp OpenCV but since I'm not much into cloud stuff and Azure explanations are confusing, I really appreciate any help with images or recorded screen showing the solution.

Based on Azure documentation, I need to a serverless framework to host code execution only.

Below is an intuitive OpenCV code and I am seeking a way to execute this. It reads an image, converts it to HSV, and saves something in an XML file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <fstream>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

Mat image;



int main()
{

    //read an image
    image = imread("water (8).png", 1);
    //check for existance of data
    if (!image.data)
    {
        printf("no image data.\n"); return -1;
    }

    if (image.isContinuous()) {
        cout << "loaded image is continuous" << "\n";
    }
    // hold HSV conversion of image
    Mat HSVimage;
    // convert to hsv - 0 <  hsvimage < 255
    cv::cvtColor(image, HSVimage, cv::COLOR_BGR2HSV);



    FileStorage PrintInXMLFile("results.xml", FileStorage::WRITE);
    PrintInXMLFile << "some_text" << "Hello!";


    PrintInXMLFile.release();//release the file after writing

    cv::waitKey(0);

    return 0;

}// end main
```

Comment: here is my code: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/349551374_OpenCV_work_demonstrating_two_hidden_layer_perceptron_NN_trained_with_RGB_intensity_values_as_feature_vector_for_segmenting_water_pixels_from_non-water_pixel_in_underwater_images

Comment: This is very broad - there are whole books on this topic. Could you perhaps get this code to run in Docker locally, so that deploying to Azure might be straightforward?

Comment: @halfer can you explain or give a link to Docker docs for running cpp code? Iguess it works for Python but not for cpp. I've added an intuitive code to qst. thank you.

Comment: Docker can run nearly anything. However, just as with Azure, Docker is a massive topic. You'll need to do some solid research and learning on either, I am afraid. Your first step is discovering whether Azure can run a Docker workload in the way that you want. For example, if you want to parallelise your work, have you worked out a way to give each program a section of it? Are the running costs acceptable to you?